# Setting the default selected item in a RadioGroup

Tags: javascript, material-ui

We are struggling to have a default value automatically set on page load for a RadioGroup. The documentation (https://material-ui.com/api/radio-group/) indicates that there is a defaultValue property, but it does not seem to take effect.

We played around with this in the Sandbox demo here and were unable to get it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8xgmd

The code taken from the Sandbox demo:

```
  <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
    <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
    <RadioGroup
      aria-label="Gender"
      name="gender1"
      className={classes.group}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      defaultValue="male">
      <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
      <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
      <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
      <FormControlLabel
        value="disabled"
        disabled
        control={<Radio />}
        label="(Disabled option)"
      />
    </RadioGroup>
  </FormControl>
```

We played around with this code but were unable to get the "male" radio button to be selected on page load. Is there another property we can set for the default?

FOLLOW UP QUESTION: we are using React 16.2. Is there a way to set the default value in that version of React?

Comment: You can just set the checked property to true for male and to false for female.

Comment: @JohnKrakov - won't work for a nested React Component that is controlled through React rather than through DOM properties.

Comment: value={value || 'male'} ?

Comment: I have experienced many times with Mateiral UI things not working because of the intial render of a component contained a non valid value, ensure you never pass an undefined value to the RadioGroup field including before the user actually sees the component.

Answer (score 0):

**If using React Version that Supports Hooks (> 16.8)**
(given stackblitz in question)

You have to use the `useState()` method the change the internal state of the React (Material Design) component. This tells MD RadioGroup component which radio button you want to be the default by creating a state property named `value` which is set to `male`. Then, the `value` property is used as the `value` attribute "value" - and that sets the default.

It is a simple change to line 24 of the sandbox referenced:

**Change:**

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("female");
```

**To:**

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("male");
```

**If using React Version without Hooks (< 16.8)**

You'll need to rewrite your function as a React Component Class using standard a state variable. Unfortunately, the version of Material Design is also an issue in this case since Material Design calls a React method that doesn't exist in the earlier version of React (`createContext()`). Downgrade Material Design to v1.0.0 if you are not using React 16.8.

And relevant code:

```js
class RadioButtonsGroup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.classes = {
      root: {
        display: "flex"
      },
      formControl: {
        margin: 13
      },
      group: {
        margin: 10
      }
    };
    this.state = {
      value: "male"
    };
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.classes.root}>
        <FormControl component="fieldset" className={this.classes.formControl}>
          <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup
            aria-label="Gender"
            name="gender1"
            className={this.classes.group}
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <FormControlLabel
              value="female"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Female"
            />
            <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
            <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="disabled"
              disabled
              control={<Radio />}
              label="(Disabled option)"
            />
          </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl component="fieldset" className={this.classes.formControl}>
          <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup
            aria-label="gender"
            name="gender2"
            className={this.classes.group}
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <FormControlLabel
              value="female"
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
              label="Female"
              labelPlacement="start"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="male"
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
              label="Male"
              labelPlacement="start"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="other"
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
              label="Other"
              labelPlacement="start"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="disabled"
              disabled
              control={<Radio />}
              label="(Disabled option)"
              labelPlacement="start"
            />
          </RadioGroup>
          <FormHelperText>labelPlacement start</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Randy. We're now getting: Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.useState is not a function with React 16.2. Do we need to upgrade?

Comment: I just confirmed that we do need to upgrade to 16.8.

Comment: is there a way to do this with React 16.2 without using hooks?

Comment: Yes and no. [Here is your Blitz rewritten to avoid hooks](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-8vrk4). That code will work.  Unfortunately, it appears Material Design will drive the upgrade either way. Downgrade React to 16.2 and you'll see the `createContext()` related error as it appears Material Design requires that method and it isn't in 16.2 (are you sure you are using 16.2 and not 16.4?)

Comment: if I take Material Design all the way back to v1.0.0 the code in my Blitz works. You must be using a very old version of MD too then.